# Get cloudformation evaluated condition value

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Is it possible to know how cloudformation evaluated a [condition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/conditions-section-structure.html)?

I have this stack:

```yaml
Parameters:
  BucketName:
    Default: ''
    Type: String
Conditions:
  CreateBucket: !Not 
    - !Equals 
      - !Ref BucketName
      - 'skip'
Resources:
  Bucket:
    Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
    Condition: CreateBucket
```

I tried to create an `Output`:

```yaml
Outputs:
  CreateBucket:
    Description: "CreateBucket"
    Value: !Ref CreateBucket
    Export:
      Name: "CreateBucket"
```

But validation fails with:

```
aws cloudformation validate-template --template-body file://"bucket.yml"

An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the ValidateTemplate operation: Unresolved resource dependencies [CreateBucket] in the Outputs block of the template
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [If](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html#intrinsic-function-reference-conditions-if) function in the output:

```
Outputs:
  CreateBucket:
    Description: "CreateBucket"
    Value: !If [CreateBucket, "true", "false"]
    Export:
      Name: "CreateBucket"
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the inability to output conditions is a specification. Condition is not among the elements that can be included in Output Value.

[Outputs - AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/outputs-section-structure.html)

> The value of an output can include literals, parameter references, pseudo-parameters, a mapping value, or intrinsic functions.